# Stop changes propagation until save button is clicked in ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

My desired scenario is that the value entered into a bound `input` field shouldn't propagate to the model until save button is clicked. I found this topic: [Emberjs: Prevent changes propagation throughout a transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14385950/emberjs-prevent-changes-propagation-throughout-a-transaction) however it's quite old. Is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try [ember-buffered-proxy](https://github.com/yapplabs/ember-buffered-proxy).

```
var buffer = BufferedProxy.create({
  content: modelInstance
});

buffer.set('name', 'something');

// apply the changes to the model
buffer.applyBufferedChanges();
modelInstance.save();

// or discard the changes
buffer.discardBufferedChanges();
```

If you bind the input to the property on `buffer` instead of `modelInstance` and call `buffer.applyBufferedChanges();` ok save it will give you the behaviour you want.

Comment: I started writing something similar myself but I was hoping that there's some built-in functionality that would work that way. Still, I'm gonna accept this answer.

Comment: What's the problem with using the mode directly? Calling `.save()` when save is pressed and `rollback()` (or the new version which I think is `rollbackAttributes()`) to revert the value back to its original state?

Comment: Interesting @jmurphyau. OP, are you using Ember Data? What is the reason why you need this different behaviour? Just curious.